# Asp.Net gridview Jquery or Ajax?

Tags: jquery, asp.net, ajax

Can anybody please help me on this.I have an Asp.Net gridview containing Startdate and Button.If startdate is greater than current date,i have to disable button.How can I achieve this using Jquery or Ajax?

Comment: when u need to disable button..?  On date select or On gridview bind

Comment: Update the code u tried..then we get an idea

Comment: I need to disable the button on gridview bind. I have tried using Rowdatabound event as below.but when the records are huge,it is taking a lot of time to display the page.                                                      if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
    {
        HtmlInputButton btnEdit = (HtmlInputButton)e.Row.FindControl("btnEdit");
 Date dtStartdate = e.Row.Cells[5].Text
 
 if((dtStartDate - (System.DateTime.Now).Days >0)
  btnEdit.Disabled = true;
     }

Answer (score 0):

try solve using looping gridview in javascript function.

i have given reference code below how to loop grid in javascript.

may it help

```
window.onload =  function ManipulateGrid() 
{
    var gvDrv = document.getElementById("<%=Gridview1.ClientID %>");
    for (i = 1; i < gvDrv.rows.length; i++) 
    {
      var cell = gvDrv.rows[i].cells;
      var HTML = cell[0].innerHTML;
      ...
      // have to put you logic here
    }
}
```